# Database SQL - How to grant and Propagate privileges?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, privileges

Given the database schema of:

```
CREATE SCHEMA Database;

CREATE TABLE DVD-Rental
(

Member-Email NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
Member_firstname NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
Member_lastname NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
Birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
DVDRentDate DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT DVDPK PRIMARY KEY (Member-Email)
)
```

How would I grant account Bob the privilege to insert and delete tuples in DVD-Rental
relation and the ability to propagate these privileges to other accounts?

For the granting Bob privileges:
I found this bit of code and adjusted it for the schema but not sure if correct or where to put it (Within the relation brackets or outside?):

```
GRANT INSERT, DELETE ON DVD-Rental TO Bob
```

Please include an SQL code solution with answers, as I don't have a clue about privileges and have struggled to find anything helpful on the internet or in books I have access to.

Thank you

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Im not actually using one, im just trying to write the code. But MS Access should be okay i think? Or SQL Server?

Comment: The search term "sql grant" would have helped you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server, you grant permissions using the statement you have designed, e.g.

```
GRANT INSERT, DELETE ON DVD-Rental TO Bob;
```

To include the ability for your user to then grant this permission to others, you need to include the `WITH GRANT OPTION` clause like so:

```
GRANT INSERT, DELETE ON DVD-Rental TO Bob WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Granting permissions is its own SQL statement so it needs to be separate from other SQL statements.  This means that you would include it outside of the parentheses of your CREATE TABLE statement.

Note that MS Access does not have any equivalent to `WITH GRANT OPTION`.